# # of invertible $n \times n$ matrices with entries in field $k$ with $q$ elements?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

What is the number of invertible $n \times n$ matrices with entries in a field $k$ with $q$ elements?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_linear_group "over finite fields"

Comment: See my answer here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1353991/determining-the-cardinality-of-sl-2-f-3/1354022#1354022

Comment: How on earth does this have 4 upvotes?  No context, and a question that has been asked multiple times previously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The row vectors of such a matrix have to be linear independent. For the first row we have $q^n-1$ possibilities. For the next row there are $q^n-q$ left and so on. So we get for the total number
$$\prod_{i=0}^{n-1} (q^n -q^i) = q^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}} \prod_{i=1}^{n} (q^i -1).$$