# Number of $2 \times 2$ matrices over the field with $3$ elements, with determinant $1$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, finite-fields, linear-groups

How can I show that the number of $2 \times 2$ matrices over the field of three elements with determinant $1$ is $24$?

Comment: The question is taken from IIT-JAM 2010 question paper

Comment: Isn't it $\Bbb{Z}_3$?

Comment: This question also has an answer here : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1353991/determining-the-cardinality-of-sl-2-f-3?noredirect=1&lq=1